# Can I access model information within the Initialize method of a controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection

In my controller I would like to set up the following services:

```
    private IAccountService _accountService;
    private IDataSourceService _dataSourceService;
    private IProductService _productService;
    private ISequenceService _sequenceService;

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
    }
```

However setting these up requires that I know the value of a property in the model that comes from the views and specifies dataSourceID.

In the Initialize method of a controller is the model information available?  If the answer is no the are session variables available for me to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want do that. The controller should not be in charge of configuring it's dependencies. You should use a Inversion of Control (aka Dependency injection) container to inject all dependencies in the constructor.

If your services require model specific information on construction I strongly suggest you review your architecture because that should not be the case. Most likely it's best to either pass that information in a method call (method injection) or abstract the dependency into a service.

In case you need information that is stored in a session, you could also consider wrapping the session in a service. You could then inject the session service as a dependency. This will also make it much easier to unit-test your controllers.

Comment: My situation is maybe unusual. I have administration screens and each screen allows a user to select a datasource from a number of different datasource locations. I was wanting to set up instances of my services in the initializer but then setting them up requires me to know what datasource the user has selected. If I don't do this in the initializer then I will have to create the instances of the services that take datasource as a parameter in each and every action.

Comment: I don't think that's very unusual; though it may require an extra abstraction since not all instances of the data access services use the same data source. You could provide a service that handles selecting the data source from a common name. If you inject that service into the data access services it will allow you to pass the data source name with each call from your action methods. If you are unable to modify the data service implementation you could create a wrapper that uses a delayed dependency creation strategy like a delegate or factory.

Answer (score 0):

Do not hack internal workings of MVC framework. It seems to me that what do you want to do is in fact **inversion of control**, or dependency injection. It is well supported in MVC, you just need to make constructor of your controller accepting these services (as interfaces) and setup IoC container (MVC3 has built-in DependencyResolver compatible with all major IoC containers - I personally like Ninject). There are many tutorials on this, and for example Ninject can be set up fully automatically via nuget.

Comment: Looking at the MSN docs I see the following: "This method cannot be called directly. Override this method in order to provide additional processing tasks before any ActionResult methods are called, such as setting the thread culture or assigning a custom provider for TempData objects." Is it not in some way saying that I could override this method to set things up for the controller methods?

Comment: No, it is not.. it is saying that overriding of initialize method is last resort when you need some nonstandard stuff (own TempData provider - i have never seen such need). Injection of services to controller is not that case and should be done in regular way - by constructor injection with IoC container.